# Can I paginate sunspot's search results without sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, sunspot

I know the standard pagination solution is:

```
Sunspot.search(Model) do
  keywords "123"
  paginate :per_page => 10
end
```

But what I need is:

```
@s = Sunspot.search(Model) do
  keywords "123"
end
magic_paginate(@s.results, :per_page => 10)
```

how to implement magic_paginate? And if I do that, the pagination still lazy-load(i.e. dont access   11th record through DB when I'm at page 1)?

Comment: Without knowing what `magic_paginate` is supposed to do, it's impossible to answer. Take a look at `will_paginate` for example. You *will* have to provide some limits/offsets to your original search; I'm not sure how your Sunspot code told Sunspot what page it was currently on.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible with kaminari gem

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(@search.results).page((params[:page] rescue 1))
```